# How do you scroll a select box to a specific point (using javascript or jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, drop-down-menu

I want to make the selected option appear in the middle of a drop-down. When I first load the page it appears at the bottom of the drop-down, but if I scroll past it and exit it remembers that when I open it again. I want it to make it appear in the middle by default.

At first I thought I could just use javascript to select an option past the one I want, then set it back to the correct option. I've played with scrollTop and scrollTo, but none of them seem to give me what I need. I've been testing it in Chrome, but it also needs to work in Firefox and IE. Any ideas?

Edit: I tried the scrollTo plugin but it doesn't seem to work for drop-downs. Take a look at these code snippets

From HTML:

```
<select id="test">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    // ........
    <option selected="selected">21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    // ........
    <option>40</option>
</select>
```

From Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    alert( $('#test option:selected').next().text() ); // alerts 22
    $().scrollTo('#test'); // scrolls the screen to the drop-down
    $('#test').scrollTo( $('#test option:selected').next() ); //does nothing
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

- [Documentation](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)
- [Demo 1](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/old/) or [Demo 2](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

**Edit - 
Final Solution:**
Because a drop-down list is brower-handled and can't be manipulated very well, you have to recreate the behavior of a drop-down list yourself. Look at the comments for more information.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for drop-downs though. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, sorry, a drop-down list is browser-handled, so you can't manipulate it very well. But you can create your own drop down control with jQuery and this plugin. Just add an ul-tag with the options, a button etc and recreate the behavior of a drop-down list with jQuery. Maybe you can find a drop-down jQuery plugin outside on the internet, too.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing. That makes sense though; from playing around with different events I was starting to get that impression (that it's handled by the browser). Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Looking at this years later, libraries like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) make dropdowns much more user- and developer-friendly, especially between browsers

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (in Chrome and Firefox):

```
<select onclick="centerSelectedOption(this)">
...
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function centerSelectedOption(selectBox) {
  var selectedIndex = selectBox.selectedIndex;
  var optionCount = selectBox.options.length
  /* browser shows 20 options at a time (as long as list is long enough)
     hence a center position of 10 would be fine
     we can achieve this by briefly selecting the (selectedIndex+10)th option 
     and then back to the actual selectedIndex */
  if (optionCount > 20) {
    var upperIndex = Math.min(optionCount, selectedIndex + 10);
    selectBox.selectedIndex = upperIndex; // hereby the browser scrolls the options list so that upperIndex is at the end

    // if the options list was already scrolled down and an option higher up is selected, we have to scroll up again
    var lowerIndex = Math.max(0, selectedIndex - 9);
    selectBox.selectedIndex = lowerIndex; // hereby the browser scrolls the options list so that lowerIndex is at the top

     // finally go back to the actually selected option
     selectBox.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

$(".MyDDL").val('2');

> [jQuery.val] checks, or selects, all
>   the radio buttons, checkboxes, and
>   select options that match the set of
>   values.

Comment: Selecting an option isn't the problem. If there are 40 items and the 30th is selected, it should show in the middle (or as close to the middle as possible) so you can see the last 10 items. By default the selected item is at the bottom and you see something like items 10-30.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem... my solution doesn't really use jquery (although the page itself does...) I thought this was more appropriate for what I was doing; and easier to implement than jquery. The problem I was having was properly making an HTML form update after javascript was used to get _GET params to pass off to ajax ... after the user hit 'submit' they would lose all of their selections.

```
function getURLParameter(param_name) {
    // get the _get parameter

    var check = decodeURI((RegExp(param_name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]);

    // get the form in the document (by id/name)

    if(typeof document.myForm[param_name]  !== 'undefined'){

        var form_param = document.myForm[param_name];

        for(key2 in form_param.options) 
            if(form_param.options[key2].value == check){
                // change index
                form_param.selectedIndex = form_param.options[key2].index;
                return check;
            }

    }
    // Return a 'null' string value if get param isn't there
    return check;
}
```